# How to resolve distorted images when pasting into a pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib, reportlab, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to generate a pdf report using `reportlab` in `python`, wherein I have first created certain visualizations - saved them as images and now I'm looking to paste them on the report.

However, in doing so the image seems distorted with an off aspect ratio. I'm not sure how to correct this, rather why this is happening.

I'm saving the image using `plt.savefig()` and drawing the image using `canvas.drawImage()`.

Example screenshot showing how it looks on pdf report:

[image: Report screenshot]

The source images look fine, when I open them as png file, while pasting the same it gets distorted.

[image: 1st image]

[image: 2nd image]

```py
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


font = "Times New Roman"
data = {'x': ['Categorical variable 1', 'Dummy text 3', 'Filers part 4', 'Ghost dataa 2'],
        'y': [10, 5, 8, 12],
        'a' : [-5,-8,-9,-10]}

total = max(data['y'])
c = canvas.Canvas("dummy.pdf", pagesize=letter)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,15))
blue= (0.67,  0.75, 0.90)
light_orange = (1.0, 0.8, 0.64)
ax = sns.barplot(x=data['y'], y=data['x'] ,orient='h', color= light_orange, width=0.6)
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fontsize=50)
plt.box(False)
ax.set_xlabel('', visible=False)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=65)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=50)
plt.yticks(fontname=font)
ax.set_ylabel('', visible=False)
#plt.rc('axes', labelsize=5)
plt.xticks(list(range(0,total,int(0.2*total))),[str(x)+'%' for x in list(range(0,110,20))])
plt.savefig(f'./Visualizations/dummy1.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(70,15))
ax1 = sns.barplot(x='y', y='x', data=data,color=blue, lw =0, width=0.6)
sns.barplot(x='a', y='x', data=data,color=light_orange, lw =0, width=0.6)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=65)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=50)
plt.yticks(fontname=font)
plt.xticks(list(range(-30,30,6)), [str(i) + '%' for i in range(-30,30,6)])
ax.set_xlabel('', visible=False)
plt.box(False)
colors = {'Y': blue, 'A':  light_orange}
labels = list(colors.keys())
handles = [plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, color=colors[label]) for label in labels]
plt.legend(handles, labels, fontsize=50)
# set the chart title
# show the chart
plt.savefig(f'./Visualizations/dummy2.png')

c.drawImage('./Visualizations/dummy1.png', 20, 625, 200,150)
c.drawImage('./Visualizations/dummy2.png', 20, 395, 450,220)
c.save()
```

Edit: Above being sample, this is kinda what the final report looks like:

[image]

As you can see there are multiple images and presently some have an off aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I need to be doing this for multiple images in the same report, I wanted to know if there's a way of getting it scaled automatically? Rather than performing hit and trial with the size?

Comment: Not really, this is more like an open project that we're working on as a 3 member team. Something similar needs to be generated for 100+ different locations and hence we're trying to automate the process

Comment: ah shucks, thanks so much, also could you please further explain what template and how do I go about creating something like that? Are you referring to something using HTML, will that not have such issues with aspect ratio when I paste the images?